# Корректно ли предложение: "Я выражаю свой протест, свое возмущение тому, что происходит"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексическая-сочетаемость

> [Я выражаю свой протест, свое возмущение тому, что происходит.](https://echo.msk.ru/blog/pozner/2355231-echo/?utm_medium=referral&utm_source=lentainform&utm_campaign=echo.msk.ru&utm_term=1274453&utm_content=6987966)

На мой взгляд, **выражают** что-то кому-то по поводу чего-то. А если "танцевать" от слова *возмущение*, то есть "возмущение чем-то / кем-то" и "возмущение по поводу чего-то", но нет "возмущения чему-либо". Прав ли я? И как приведенную фразу понимать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данное предложение **некорректно** безотносительно "возмущения": "выражать (что-либо) тому" является прямым *обращением* к неодушевлённой сущности, поименованной местоимением.

Более интересен родственный вопрос: можно ли *возмущаться чему-либо* (вместо "чем-либо"). В словарях не удаётся найти варианта "возмущаться чему" (в отличие от удивиться чему/кому), хотя единичные случаи такого употребления встречаются у современных прозаиков (в старой публицистике с такой фразеологией попалась только цитата высказывания барона Энгельгардта). Видимо, традиционно закрепилась норма "чем", как указание на *причину* возникшей эмоции возмущения, в то время как "направленность" (чему, в направлении чего при этом глядя и т. п. - ср. с удивлением) не придаёт выразительности такому высказыванию. Всё это подкрепляет вывод о некорректности исходной фразы.